# Are certain English words cognates to Old English words?

Tags: etymology, old-english, old-norse

For example, the English word *spoor* comes right from the Afrikaans *spoor*, meaning trail or track. This is from an identical Dutch word which is descended from the Proto-Germanic **spurą*, from which came an Old English word- *spor*. (Also *spurn*)

Another example of this is with *valkyrie*, the English word for the choosers of the slain in Norse mythology. Etymonline [says it entered English in the 1700s](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Valkyrie), from the Old Norse. (From *valr* + *kjósa*, the Proto-Germanic roots of which are from where *choose* and the Middle English *wal* come from.) However, Old English had a word for the Valkyries 
too- *wælcyrge*.

So my question is, can we call valkyrie and spoor (plus similar borrowings, like falcon when we had the Old English *fealca*) cognates of the Old English words, or are they just borrowings?

Answer (score 6):

They are both cognates, and borrowings.

They are indeed related to the Old English words, which makes them cognates. However, because they (as I take it) fell out of usage before being borrowed into the language, they are also what the people who spoke at the time took them to be: borrowings. They were not aware that cognates once existed in a past form of their language. That is why it is both.

Comment: +1 Interesting, indeed. Anything by way of 'Further Reading?'

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Perhaps the best analogy I can give you is this:

Triple is a borrowing from Latin, and is related to English thrice. I would say this is both a word that is cognate to the English, and a borrowing at the same time.